# Issue finding xpath

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am having an issue finding text inside this element. There are no errors when the driver starts. Is my syntax correct?

```
<span id="container" class="contact-wrap">
<a id="contact-link" href="contact.html"><i class="icon"></i> (hidden) <span 
class="contact-address"></span></a>
</span>
```

Have Tried

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='contact-link']/span[2][contains(text(),' (hidden) ')]")
```

Comment: There is only one `span` inside the element that matches, so don't test the second. But that text is *also* not inside the `span` so don't test for that at all. It seems you got some wrong ideas about xpath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to select all `a` elements where the first non-empty `text()` node contains the string `(hidden)` then use this XPath:

```
//a[@id='contact-link' and contains(text(),' (hidden) ')]
```

But this only works for the first node.

Comment: I think I understand it now! and seems to work. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This will work.

```
>>> element = driver.find_element_by_id('contact-link')
>>> element.text
'(hidden)'
>>>
```